# How to generate all .o files for each .c file when compiling a Linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, compilation

I need to generate bitcode files for each .c file for analysis, so I modified my clang as following:

```
--- llvm-project2/llvm/lib/Transforms/IPO/DeadArgumentElimination.cpp   2020-02-03 20:57:16.473409308 +0000
+++ llvm-project/llvm/lib/Transforms/IPO/DeadArgumentElimination.cpp    2020-02-03 20:44:32.478661999 +0000
@@ -49,6 +49,10 @@
 #include <utility>
 #include <vector>
 
+
+#include "llvm/Bitcode/BitcodeWriter.h"
+#include "llvm/Support/ToolOutputFile.h"
+
 using namespace llvm;
 
 #define DEBUG_TYPE "deadargelim"
@@ -1084,6 +1088,22 @@
 
 PreservedAnalyses DeadArgumentEliminationPass::run(Module &M,
                                                    ModuleAnalysisManager &) {
+ 
+  // write out bitcode
+  
+  //outs() << "DeadArg Elimination on " << M.getName() << "\n";
+  std::string FileName = M.getSourceFileName();
+  if(FileName.find(".c") != FileName.npos){
+    std::string Path = M.getSourceFileName() + ".bc";
+    outs() << "Writing to " << Path << "\n";
+    std::error_code EC;
+    raw_fd_ostream out(Path, EC, sys::fs::F_None);
+    WriteBitcodeToFile(M, out);
+    out.flush();
+    out.close();
+    outs() << "Write Done";
+  }
+
   bool Changed = false;
 
   // First pass: Do a simple check to see if any functions can have their "..."
```

and compiled linux kernel with my customized clang. However, I didn't get all my .bc file for each .c file.

Is there something wrong with my compilation instruction?

```
make CC="/path/to/clang" -j$(nproc)
```

and what should I do to generate all .o files for each .c file, and get my bitcode files?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, but compiling every **.c** file in the Linux kernel makes no sense because you're supposed to specify (and build for) only one **ARCH**. The **CC** environment variable is supposed to specify the toolchain prefix, rather than a path (although this is sometimes abused).

Comment: is it possible that `DeadArgumentEliminationPass::run()` only executes when there are dead arguments found? So you'd only get your `.bc` files on `Module`s with dead arguments

Comment: @sawdust: "The CC environment variable is supposed to specify the toolchain prefix" - You probably confused `CC` variable with `CROSS_COMPILE`. The latter one actually specifies a prefix. The former is specifies the compiler executable (absolute path or filename).

Comment: You can configure the kernel with `make allyesconfig` to include more or less everything that makes sense for the architecture.

Comment: @IanAbbott, to complement this you also need `make allmodconfig` since not everything can be builtin.